# Issue with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I created LINQ implementation of [mod10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) algorithm.

The source code:

```
string number = "7992739871";
int mod10sum = number.Reverse()
    .Select((c, i) => (c - '0') << ((i + 1) & 1)) // Double every other digit and sum the digits of the products (e.g., 10: 1 + 0 = 1, 14: 1 + 4 = 5) 
    .Sum(c => c - '0') % 10;                      // together with the undoubled digits from the original number

string checkDigit = (mod10sum == 0 ? 0 : 10 - mod10sum).ToString("0");
Console.WriteLine(checkDigit);
```

As per the [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), `7992739871` number should have check digit as `3`; however, what I am getting is `15`.

What I am doing wrong? I am sure the mistake is very small but can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the `Sum`.

At this point, you don't have a sequence of characters, but the single-or-doubled-as-appropriate value for each original digit.

Thus, you don't need to be subtracting `0`, you need to be calculating the digit sum of each of these integers, and (since you know they'll be small) you can do this as simply as

```
.Sum(i => (i % 10) + (i / 10))
```

giving

```
string number = "7992739871";
int mod10sum = number.Reverse()
    .Select((c, i) => (c - '0') << ((i + 1) & 1)) 
    .Sum(i => (i % 10) + (i / 10)) % 10;
```

This should be more effecient than calling `ToString()` and iterating over the result.

Comment: I really like this one (+1). Definitelly no issue with `int` to `string` conversion

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with the `Select` method. In order to sum up all the digits (as described in the algorithm) you would need to return `1` and `0` instead of `10`, `1` and `4` instead of `14` (as in your example).

The **easiest** (**but it does not have to be the most optimal**) way to do that is to conert number from `Select` to `string` (14 -> "14") and then split the string characters using `SelectMany`.

So your code should look as follows:

```
int mod10sum = number.Reverse()
    .SelectMany((c, i) => ((c - '0') << ((i + 1) & 1)).ToString())
    .Sum(c => c - '0') % 10;

checkDigit = (mod10sum == 0 ? 0 : 10 - mod10sum).ToString("0");
Console.WriteLine(checkDigit);
```

**A bit of theory**

LINQ [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) returns `IEnumerable<>`. When you return `string` (which is IEnumerable) then that's why `SelectMany` "splits" returned string into characters.

Microsoft has very nice page ([101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)) with different LINQ samples which should help you out.

**EDIT**

I would also recommend working on that conversion from `int` to `string`. I was working on similar project literally yesterday and in my case that conversion is a bit problematic from performance point of view as we call that method millions of times. If you have to calculate lots of mod10's then it might be not the best solution.

Comment: Not possible to type this (and add links etc) in just one minute. So i assume that the OP and Tom are linked somehow ;)

Comment: @Tom, I really like your solution but will accept Rawling's one as it does not have mentioned performance problem. And thanks for the link to 101 LINQ.